# ClassCastException Object cannot be cast to

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception

I don't understand why I get **`ClassCastException`** on below code in line:

```
for(int i = 0; i < k.t.length; i++)
```

So problem is that in method `addElement` I make replacing of array elements by objects with type T. In my opinion in array should be objects with type T. And compiler doesn't protest for that. 
But in run-time JVM cannot cast despite in array is really objects with type T (in case below String), why JVM cannot use polymorphism?

But when I change the  `T[] t;` to `Object[] t;`

and remove cast in constructor it run correctly without any errors, why?

```
public class MyCollection<T> {

    T[] t;

    MyCollection( int size){
        t = (T[]) new Object[size];
    }

    boolean addElement(T e, int i){        
        if(i < t.length){
            t[i] = e;
            return true;
        }
        return false;            
    }

    public static void main(String[] ss){

        MyCollection<String> k = new MyCollection<String>(3);

        k.addElement("a",0);
        k.addElement("b",1);
        k.addElement("c",2);

        for(int i = 0; i < k.t.length; i++)
            System.out.println(k.t[i]);     

        //for(String s : (String[])k.t)
        //    System.out.println(s);        
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need `k.t[0].toString()`

Comment: @algui91: no, println already does that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-generic-array-creation

Comment: @algui91 The problem isn't on System.out.println(k.t[0]); but on for(int i = 0; i < k.t.length; i++)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're casting `Object[]` to `T[]`, and then you're exposing the underlying array. The only reason this works altogether is because the type erasure of `T` is `Object`. But since in our case `T` is being interpreted as `String`, when we access the array externally, we're trying to cast it to `String[]`, which is incorrect. In order to avoid this issue, you should make the array private and provide accessor methods to retrieve elements. By doing that, you only cast individual elements to their correct type without making assumptions about the underlying array.

```
public class MyCollection<T> {

    private T[] t;

    MyCollection( int size){
        t = (T[]) new Object[size];
    }

    boolean addElement(T e, int i){        
        if(i < t.length){
            t[i] = e;
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    T getElement(int index) {
        return t[index];
    }

    int getLength() {
        return t.length;
    }

    public static void main(String[] ss){

        MyCollection<String> k = new MyCollection<String>(3);

        k.addElement("a",0);
        k.addElement("b",1);
        k.addElement("c",2);

        for(int i = 0; i < k.getLength(); i++)
            System.out.println(k.getElement(i));     

        //for(String s : (String[])k.t)
        //    System.out.println(s);        
     }
}
```

Note that Java's `Collection` interface demonstrates the same behavior. [Collection.toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28%29) returns `Object[]` regardless of the type of `E`. The only available workaround is [Collection.toArray(T[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29), where you're forced to pass an array with a fixed type, which can then be either be populated or copied.

Comment: It would also break type-safety to allow such a cast (Object[] to T[]), as there is no way to statically determine whether your Object-array contains only T's.

Comment: @SebastianOkon As long as the array is internally managed, you can be certain it will always contain `T`s. In that case, using an array of `T` lets you skip casting values to `T` upon retrieval.

Comment: I did not meant to disagree to you. If it is implemented like this it is fine. Nevertheless this is potentially dangerous as you do not get any warning in case you make some changes/extensions later.

Answer (score 1):

Check again the line of the problem. In my opinion the exception will be thrown because of:

```
    for(String s : (String[])k.t)
```

You`re trying to cast to String[] here, while the array is defined as Object[]:

```
t = (T[]) new Object[size];
```

Comment: But he says the error is in the first loop `for(int i = 0; i < k.t.length; i++)`

Comment: The sample problem occurs in the first loop.  It's really equivalent to `for (int i = 0; i < ((String[])k.t).length); i++)`.

Comment: You can look how own collection with array can be made in http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java

Answer (score 0):

you can Create a new instance of array using the reflection to avoid `ClassCastException`

**example:**

```
    import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class MyCollection<T> {

    T[] t;

    MyCollection(Class<T> clazz, int size) {
        t = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, size);

    }

    boolean addElement(T e, int i) {
        if (i < t.length - 1) {
            t[i] = e;
            return true;
        }
        return false;

    }

    public static void main(String[] ss) {

        MyCollection<String> k = new MyCollection<String>(String.class, 3);

        k.addElement("a", 0);
        k.addElement("b", 1);
        k.addElement("c", 2);

        for (int i = 0; i < k.t.length; i++)
            System.out.println(k.t[0]);

    }
}
```

Comment: I know that I can do that. But I'm instresting why I cannot do as I write.

Comment: So problem is that in method addElement I make replacing of array elements by objects with type T. In my opinion in array should be objects with type T. And compiler doesn't protest for that. But in run-time JVM cannot cast despite in array is really objects with type T (in case below String), why JVM cannot use polymorphism?

Comment: @LunaVulpo that is beause java doesnt know what T is and therefore cant use polymorphism due to that.